# Query not well formed in Sqlalchemy for select

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to generate the following raw query using sqlalchemy core:

> SELECT library.name, (SELECT ARRAY (select book.title from books where
> book.library_id = 1 and book.is_free = false) as book_lists) from
> library where id = 1;

So the query I generate in sqlalchemy is:

```
query = sa.select(
  [
    library.name,
    sa.func.array(
      sa.select(
        [books.title]
      ).where(
        sa.and_(
          books.c.library_id == library_no,
          books.c.is_free == False,
        )
      ).alias('members')
    )
  ]
).where(
   library.c.id == library_no,
)
```

But the queries aren't equivalent

#### TL; DR:

Here are the table that I have in my postgresql:

Table: **library**

```
--------------------------------
| id |    name     |    owner  |
--------------------------------
|  1 |     ABC     |     A     |
|  2 |     DEF     |     D     |
|  3 |     GHI     |     G     |
--------------------------------
```

Table: **books**

```
-----------------------------------------
| id |    title    |  library  | is_free |
-----------------------------------------
|  a |     xxx     |     1     |    t    |
|  b |     yyy     |     1     |    f    |
|  c |     zzz     |     2     |    t    |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Replacing `.alias('members')` with `.as_scalar()` will give you SQL that is the same as the psql example.  Not this will only work as expected when the subquery in the `array()` call returns only one row.

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb. Please write as the answer so I can make it the answer. And could you further help how to rename the column

Comment: I solved it with the `label` method. :D